# Как вытащить все url из json файла?

Tags: javascript

Как вытащить все url из файла json, чтобы потом отправить их на страницу. Не нужно указывать имя "galleryImages", потому что файлы постоянно будут разные и мне из них нужно будет вытаскивать url.Возможно ли не указывая имен массивов собрать эти url?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
let object = {
    .......
    .......
};

let urls = Object.values(test)[0].map(item => item.url);
```